# Trying to extract common functionality among these

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, refactoring

I have below method where i am using reducer to set these dictionaries "earliestOptionByInitialRevision" and "latestOptionByInitialRevision" inside the reducer and the code is looks like as below

```
 const lookups = optionsInput?.reduce(
    (acc, option) => {
      const [optionById, earliestOptionByInitialRevision, latestOptionByInitialRevision] = acc;
      optionById[option.id] = option;
      const isCustomProject = option.initialRevisionId === null || option.initialRevisionId === undefined;
      if (
        isCustomProject ||
        !earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId] ||
        option.revision < earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId].revision
      ) {
          // trying to extract the below into common 
          //function because in  below if condition i have used the same and difference is
         // "earliestOptionByInitialRevision"

        if (isCustomProject) { 
          option = {...option, initialRevisionId:'customProjectOption'}
          if (!earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId]) 
          {
            earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId] = [option];
          } else {
            earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId].push(option);
          }
        } else {
          earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId] = option;
        }
      }
      if (
        isCustomProject ||
        !latestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId] ||
        option.revision > latestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId].revision
      ) {
        // the below if condition same as with above and the difference            
        // is "latestOptionByInitialRevision"

        if (isCustomProject) { 
          option = {...option, initialRevisionId:'customProjectOption'}
          if (!latestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId]) {
            latestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId] = [option];
          } else {
            latestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId].push(option);
          }
        } else {
          latestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId] = option;
        }
      }
      return acc;
    },
    [{}, {}, {}]
  ) ?? [{}, {}, {}];

  const [optionById, earliestOptionByInitialRevision, latestOptionByInitialRevision] = lookups;
```

i would like to extract the below common functionality but could not be able to get through on how to achieve the same. Could any  one please help on this that would be very grateful to me

```
  if (isCustomProject) {
    option = {...option, initialRevisionId:'customProjectOption'}
    if (!earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId]) {
      earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId] = [option];
    } else {
      earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId].push(option);
    }
  } else {
    earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId] = option;
  }
```

Many thanks in advance
update:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix could be to extract the common functionality into a function, parameterised by the dict (JavaScript object).

```js
const optionsInput = [{
    id: 1,
    revision: 2
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    revision: 1
  },
];

  const lookups = optionsInput?.reduce(
    (acc, option) => {
      const [optionById, earliestOptionByInitialRevision, latestOptionByInitialRevision] = acc;
      optionById[option.id] = option;
      const isCustomProject = option.initialRevisionId === null || option.initialRevisionId === undefined;

      const updateDict = (dict) => {
          if (isCustomProject) {
            const newOption = {...option, initialRevisionId:'customProjectOption'}
            if (!dict[option.initialRevisionId]) {
              dict[option.initialRevisionId] = [newOption];
            } else {
              dict[option.initialRevisionId].push(newOption);
            }
          } else {
            dict[option.initialRevisionId] = option;
          }
      };
      
      if (isCustomProject || !earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId] || option.revision < earliestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId].revision) {
        updateDict(earliestOptionByInitialRevision);
      }
      
      if (isCustomProject || !latestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId] || option.revision > latestOptionByInitialRevision[option.initialRevisionId].revision) {
        updateDict(latestOptionByInitialRevision);
      }
      
      return acc;
    },
    [{}, {}, {}]
  ) ?? [{}, {}, {}];

console.log(lookups);
```

Comment: sorry getting an error like `assignment to function parameter `option` and `dict` at this line `option = {...option, initialRevisionId:'customProjectOption'}` and `dict[option.initialRevisionId] = [option];`

Comment: could you please let me know how to overcome this error

Comment: but at that time i did not get any error but now it is showing and same for `dict` as well

Comment: Can you share what `optionsInput` looks like to get a better idea of the original problem?

Comment: i just uploaded image about options input and its list of objects

Comment: Code snippet seems to run fine

Comment: nope looks like with these i have some other problems

Comment: Just updated snippet to avoid assignment to function params

Comment: i just want to refactor only inside that if conditions because outer side if conditions are having different conditions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230789/discussion-between-anson-miu-and-enigma-state).